# Can someone help me diagnose my cats tail

Tags: cats, first-aid

Recently our cat came back after a fight; he seemed beat, but we didn't notice anything with his tail. Him getting into fights is not as uncommon as you might think because he was a stray before we took him in and he was constantly getting into fights then. The next day he seemed more aggravated than usual and his tail was limp. We think he broke his tail but we don't know the severity. If anyone has any knowledge about this I'd really appreciate it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPbHE.jpg

Comment: your cat need a vet to diagnose and treat this,the tail and hip area will often be injured when cats fight.it is impossible to tell if this is a broken bone or an infection without seeing the cat.the cat might even have been hit by a car so you need to get your cat to the vet.

Comment: If your cat is injured, you NEED to go to a vet. People on the internet can't treat your cat.